# Determine if app was launched from home screen?

Tags: android

In my main activity, onCreate I set a textView to the current date. From that activity, I startActivityForResult activity2, where I can change the date. onActivityResult, I set the textView to whatever date was returned.

Now, if you close the main activity and the textView is not the current date. The next time you open it (from the button on home screen or app drawer), I would like it to set the textView to the current date.

After it opens for the first time, the next time you open it, it doesn't hit onCreate. I've tried using onResume however this prevents activity2 onActivityResult from changing the date.

Comment: your question is not clear, plz elaborate little more

Comment: Could you please provide code snippets so we can see exactly where you want to call what? Also, do you have a full understanding of the android lifecycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

First of all, create an [`onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) method and save the current contents of the date `TextView` to it. This is called before Android stops, hides, or destroys your activity.

When you start activity2, your `onStop()` of activity1 will be called. In there, set a flag to indicate whether or not `onStop()` is called due to you starting a new activity (make the intent for activity2 a member, not local variable for this). Ensure you save this flag in `onSaveInstanceState` of activity1.

Implement `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)` in activity1, and restore to local variables the date and flag values.

Finally, in `onResume` of activity1, check the flag - it you are resuming because you are returning from activity2, do not change the TextView since that will be set in `onActivityResult`, otherwise, you can safely restore the saved date value.

Answer (score 2):

Try to save the value of the date from activity2 into the android SharedPreferences.

You can set the date to the preferences by using something like this:

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
prefsEditor.putString(MY_NAME, "Sai");
prefsEditor.putString(MY_WALLPAPER, "f664.PNG");
prefsEditor.commit();
```

and you can read the preferences by using something like that:

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
String prefName = myPrefs.getString(MY_NAME, "nothing");
String wallPaper = myPrefs.getString(MY_WALLPAPER, null);
```

Set a flag like "dateWasAlreadySet" to the SharedPreferences if the date was set from activty2, so you know that the date was already set.

Pseudo Code:

```
If(SharedPreferences.dateWasAlreadySet){
    activity1.textField.text = SharedPreferences.get("myDate");
} else {
    activity1.textField.text = currentDate;
}
```

I hope you understand what I mean.