# how to check whether the activity was launched from notification or from the user click on home screen dashboard app icon in android

Tags: android

how to check whether the activity was launched from notification or from the user click on home screen dashboard app icon in android. Is there any parameters that tells that this activity was launched due to user clicked on notification..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There already were several questions on this topic:

- [detecting application launch from
  home or history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447912/android-detecting-application-launch-from-home-or-history)
- [Determine if app was launched from
  home screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582432/determine-if-app-was-launched-from-home-screen)

As of the home screen part, as far as I know there is no way to detect that.

However, you can detect whether your activity is launched from the notification icon:

When setting up your notification, you put an extra into it's `PendingIntent`, say `fromNotification: boolean`. 
In your main activity's `onCreate` method you check the intent's extras, and if (there are any and) the `fromNotification` is among them with the value `true`, than you know it has been invoked by clikcing on the notification icon.

Comment: For launch from home screen, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789300/is-there-any-way-to-distinguish-between-an-android-activity-onresume-from-the-hom

Comment: That's right, but the `onNewIntent` will be called from the notification's intent too (and every resume regardless to launchMode), if the application was not in the background and so got garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) when launching Activity from your App and then check if [getCallingActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity%28%29) returns `null`. If it does, your activity has been launched from notification.